# Breadth First Search using array

Tags: c++, arrays, breadth-first-search, maze

I am trying to implement Breadth First Search for a maze using arrays. The problem I'm facing now is that I cant expand the paths at the same time. Something like this:

```
#######
123456#
#3###7#
#4###8#
#5###9G
#######
```

The method I'm now currently using is using a for loop to loop through the array. I set the starting point to be C (current) and the end point to be G (goal).
When I iterate through the maze, I search for the array location that store the character 'C'. Then i checked if up, down, left, right is a wall. If not, I'll moved to the next bracket. The new bracket I would set it as 'C' and the previous bracket I set it 'O'.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            // find current node
            if (maze[i][j] == 'C')
            {

            if (maze[i][j-1] == ' ')       // up
                {
                    maze[i][j-1] = 'C';
                    maze[i][j] = 'O';
                }

                else if (maze[i][j+1] == ' ')       // down
                {
                    maze[i][j+1] = 'C';
                    maze[i][j] = 'O';
                }

                else if (maze[i-1][j] == ' ')       // left
                {
                    maze[i-1][j] = 'C';
                    maze[i][j] = 'O';
                }
                else if (maze[i+1][j] == ' ')
                {
                    maze[i+1][j] = 'C';
                    maze[i][j] = 'O';  

                  }
    }
```

How do I implement for the part where the 'C' bracket is at a junction? I using a for loop so it keep coming out like this:

```
#######   #######   #######   #######  #######  #######  #######  #######
C     #   OC    #   OOC   #   OOOC  #  OOOOC #  OOOOOC#  OOOOOO#  OOOOOO#
# ### #   # ### #   #C### #   #C### #  #C### #  #C### #  #O###C#  #O###O#
# ### #   # ### #   # ### #   # ### #  # ### #  # ### #  #C### #  #O###C#
# ###     # ###     # ###     # ###    # ###    # ###    # ###    #C### 
#######   #######   #######   #######  #######  #######  #######  #######
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't literally expand the paths simultaneously in BFS. Instead, you put the first element into a queue, and then iteratively pop the first element from the front and then add all elements to the back of the queue that are reachable from that element and not contained in the queue already.

You are trying to work on the *map* only; this is not possible with BFS. You need a queue that contains the positions of the visited elements and a way to mark elements as done.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search has a nice example for that.

Comment: So its not possible to do it this way?

Comment: No. You would need e.g. a `std::queue<Vector2>` (where `Vector2` is a suitable 2D int data type, such as std::pair<int,int>) that stores your canidate list. Then, you can put your candidate positions (`C` in your example) there, and mark visited positions (`O`) directly in the map.

Comment: Can you give me a headstart? A simple example maybe?

Comment: Sorry, don't have much time right now. I would suggest having a look at that Wikipedia article I linked, and coming back if you still have any questions.